# ¿Como poner animacion a un widget flotante en Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-widget, widget

Estoy en el desarrollo de una aplicación la cual tiene un widget flotante que tiene el permiso android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW para aparecer encima, y dicho widget se puede mover. Necesito poder mover el widget hacia la izquierda o derecha a modo de animación cuando el usuario lo deje en la mitad de la pantalla, he investigado y tengo el siguiente código para hacer eso (El cual no funciona):

```
        private void resetPosition()
        {
        Timer Timer1 = new Timer();
        Timer1.Interval = 150;
        Timer1.Enabled = true;
        int counter = 5;

        Timer1.Start();
        Timer1.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            counter--;
            var valor = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.aaa);
            valor.Text = counter;
            layoutParams.X = layoutParams.X * counter;
            windowManager.UpdateViewLayout(floatingView, layoutParams);
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                Timer1.Stop();
            }
        };
```

Este código se llama al momento cuando el usuario deja de presionar el widget. Aquí el código

```
     public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                initialX = layoutParams.X;
                initialY = layoutParams.Y;

                initialTouchX = e.RawX;
                initialTouchY = e.RawY;
                return true;

            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                layoutParams.X = initialX + (int)(e.RawX - initialTouchX);
                layoutParams.Y = initialY + (int)(e.RawY - initialTouchY);

                closeFloatingView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                windowManager.UpdateViewLayout(floatingView, layoutParams);

                return true;

            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                closeFloatingView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

                initialX = layoutParams.X;
                initialY = layoutParams.Y;

                resetPosition();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

También necesito enviar el dato de la variable counter a un textview y me sale error en el FindViewById.

Les agradezco mucho su ayuda.